# React-Popper + custom Components using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-popper

I have a set of Components that should not use react-popper internally.
I'm trying to have them be used as Reference with [react-popper](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper).
I get that the solution is to use forwardRef, however, I spent hours trying to do it without great success.

Is there any way someone could provide a sample for a simple case ?
Here is a simple textbox Component that needs an internal ref : how should it be rewritten or wrapped to be used as a Reference ?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Textbox = ({
  autofocus,
  ...props
}) => {
  // handle auto-focus
  const node = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (autofocus) {
      // focus & select the whole text
      node.current.focus();
      node.current.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
    }
  },
  // do it only once
  []);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      ref={node}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure! To use this Textbox component as a reference with react-popper, you'll need to use `React.forwardRef` to create a new component that passes the `ref` to the underlying `input` element. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, forwardRef } from 'react';

const Textbox = forwardRef(({
  autofocus,
  ...props
}, ref) => {
  // handle auto-focus
  const node = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (autofocus) {
      // focus & select the whole text
      node.current.focus();
      node.current.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
    }
  }, [autofocus]);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      ref={ref || node}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});

export default Textbox;
```

Here, we're using `forwardRef` to create a new component that accepts a `ref` as a prop, and passes it along to the underlying `input` element. We're also using `useRef` to create a local ref that we can use to access the `input` element if no `ref` prop is provided.

Note that we've added a default value of `null` to the `useRef` call, and we're passing `[autofocus]` to the `useEffect` hook to avoid a missing dependency warning.

With this setup, you should be able to use the `Textbox` component as a reference with react-popper like so:

```
import { usePopper } from 'react-popper';
import Textbox from './Textbox';

function MyComponent() {
  const [referenceElement, setReferenceElement] = useState(null);
  const [popperElement, setPopperElement] = useState(null);
  const { styles, attributes } = usePopper(referenceElement, popperElement);

  return (
    <>
      <Textbox ref={setReferenceElement} />
      <div ref={setPopperElement} style={styles.popper} {...attributes.popper}>
        ...
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here, we're passing the `setReferenceElement` function to the `ref` prop of the `Textbox` component, which allows us to access the `input` element later on with `referenceElement`. We're also passing the `setPopperElement` function to a `div` element that we want to position relative to the `input` element using react-popper. We're using the `usePopper` hook to calculate the positioning of the `div`, and we're applying the resulting `styles` and `attributes` to the `div` using spread syntax.

Comment: I succeeded in doing that years ago and I did as you described. Very good answer sir !